# Create and display 10-bit images on a 10-bit monitor

Tags: image-processing, colors, display, image-recognition, vision

As part of a visual recognition experiment, I need to generate 10-bit images pixel-by-pixel and display them on the monitor (10 bits per color). I would like to understand how this can be implemented programmatically, using what programming language and what libraries. I am more of a scientist than a programmer, I know Matlab and Python, but I couldn’t find the option for 10-bit output in these tools. More precisely, the output seems to be possible, but these must be images like HDR, and I need to generate images in the program so that each pixel has 1024 gradations, which would be reproduced by the monitor. In terms of hardware, it has everything you need for 10-bit output. I will be glad to receive any help.

Among the Python libraries, I couldn’t find any that would support 10-bit output, only the processing of such images. In Matlab I found such an opportunity, but only for HDR images.

Comment: You probably need to know about the monitor and its driver. I don’t think there’s a generic way to do this (though I might be wrong).

Comment: It's probably a good idea to state your acceptable operating systems here as custom drivers may be necessary.